# mongo update multiple items in sublist by id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to update multiple items in a list of an item that is inside a list,

the update I want to make is different for every item
`_id:1` should change its time to 5:50 and `_id:2` to a 8:40
ex:

```
[
  {
    "user_id": "121212121",
    "list": [
      {
        "employee_code": 8131,
        "list": [
          {
            // update me by my _id to 5:50!!!
            "_id": "1",
            "time": "5:20",
          },
          {
           // update me by my _id to 8:40!!!
            "_id": "2",
            "time": "8:20",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

couldnt manage to do that.

Comment: what update you want to make? is that is same update for all matched _id of sub documents? did you have a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

Comment: your right Ill edit my question

Comment: @ProgrammerAnalyst edited!

Comment: posted solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pls refer to https://mongoplayground.net/p/MCOSbe0LfM-  to update _id:1

```
db.collection.update({
  "list.list._id": "1"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "list.$[].list.$[idmatch].time": "5:50"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "idmatch._id": "1"
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

and refer to https://mongoplayground.net/p/dDalHmLBEbY to update _id:2

```
    db.collection.update({
  "list.list._id": "2"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "list.$[].list.$[idmatch].time": "8:40"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "idmatch._id": "2"
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

Here we have used the $[identifier] https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#mongodb-update-up.---identifier--

Note: i set here multi true so if multiple documents found all will be updated.

in case you need to update in one update the pls refer to https://mongoplayground.net/p/tBpmPccP6ml

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  "$set": {
    "list.$[].list.$[idmatch1].time": "5:50",
    "list.$[].list.$[idmatch2].time": "8:40"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "idmatch1._id": "1"
    },
    {
      "idmatch2._id": "2"
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

Comment: my question is how to do that at once and not one by one like providing an array of ids and find each ID and update it with a diff value

Comment: ok here you go...  https://mongoplayground.net/p/tBpmPccP6ml  db.collection.update({},
{
  "$set": {
    "list.$[].list.$[idmatch1].time": "5:50",
    "list.$[].list.$[idmatch2].time": "8:40"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "idmatch1._id": "1"
    },
    {
      "idmatch2._id": "2"
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})

Comment: what is the `idmatch` ?

Comment: its identifier to match subdocument for update https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/  if you see in update $set i have used $[idmatch1] and $[idmatch2] so here i created two array filters one each for different criteria to update. As idmatch1 or idmatch2 is just a variable you can use any name you want but pls ensure in array filters you use same names though.

Comment: That a great answer you provided very impressive TY helped me a lot!